# Locally store results list in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedures, cursor

In a stored procedure I have to locally store results from iterative calculations for each item in a table.
Results should be used at next iteration.
At the end of procedure run, a table with item|value fields should be returned.
I have 3 main requirements:

1. work on "crystallized" data at the time of procedure launch: resolved with STATIC cursor
2. let the procedure to be called concurrently by different users without collisions: resolved with LOCAL cursor
3. store locally table of results between iterations.

For this last requirement I was hoping to create a temp table with random name:

```
set @tempTable = 'temp_table'+cast(rand()*1000 as varchar(10))
```

but http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table highly discourages this and LOCAL STATIC cursors aren't updatable, so what to use?
Iteratively call the same procedure would be complicated by the fact that I have to keep initial source data static, regardless of database content modifications that can happen during calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **[table variable](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-table-variables)**, I think this is what you are lokking for. They are all in memory, and isolated between different connections.

Comment: so table variables (and thus variables) are inherently local to procedure in which they are declared? Should I specify some LOCAL property?

Comment: A table variable goes out of scope immediately after the batch ends -- just like regular variables, so yes they are local.

Comment: Wow! That's THE solution. Thnx!